# 403 Error when overwriting feature layer in ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, feature-service, authentication, arcgis-python-api

I'm attempting to overwrite a hosted layer that I own in ArcGIS Online using the arcgis.features.FeatureLayerCollection.manager.overwrite() method in Python. However, I keep receiving a 403 Error even though I'm logged in with the appropriate credentials. The hosted feature layer has editing enabled and I'm using [OAuth2.0](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/working-with-different-authentication-schemes/) to authenticate since when I login to AGOL normally it redirects me to my organization's sign-in page.

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS
    from IPython.display import display
    import os
    import glob
    import pandas as pd
    directory = r'G:/Shared drives/path/'
    file_pattern = '*.csv'
    latest_file = max(glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, file_pattern)), key=os.path.getctime)
    df = pd.read_csv(latest_file)

    from arcgis.features import FeatureLayerCollection
    gis = GIS("https://uwyo.maps.arcgis.com", client_id = "XXXXXXXXXXXX", client_secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" ) 
    fs = gis.content.get('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX') 
    fs = FeatureLayerCollection.fromitem(fs)
    
    fs.manager.overwrite(df)


Exception: User does not have permissions to access this service
User does not have permissions to access this service
(Error Code: 403)
```

[image]

Comment: Is your account an administrator, own the feature service, or is that item shared into a group with update capabilities?

Comment: @evv_gis I own the feature service and the item is not shared with a group. In settings I have that editing is allowed

Comment: Was the original item published from ArcGIS Pro/ArcMap or did you upload a CSV table to ArcGIS Online and publish a layer from that? It looks like depending on how the hosted item was created, the overwrite procedure varies in success.  [Reference](https://community.esri.com/t5/python-questions/how-to-update-a-hosted-table-in-agol-using-python/m-p/510276#M40101).

Comment: I uploaded as a CSV table and published it from there

Comment: You need to update the CSV item and not the published feature layer item.

Comment: I get the same error that I don't have permission when I try to update the CSV item rather than the published feature item: 
fs = gis.content.get('XXXXXXX') 
fs.update({}, r'path/to/.csv')

Comment: Unsure of the permissions issue if you're the owner of the item.  However, I did see a post where others had issues with a similar approach, and ended up using a [GeoAccessor](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-api-for-python-questions/update-hosted-table-overwriting-it-with-local-csv/td-p/1078942/page/2).